# How to create a zip file with PDF files with the addFromString function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, zip

I have this code broken down into two parts:

- The first one create me a zip file empty and download it.
- The second one download me from my database a PDF file that I decoded in base64.

Both work well separately. I would like to be able to merge them and download in zip format two PDF files that are in my database.

I would like to use the `addFromString` function to not create a folder on my server but to download the zip file directly for the user.

Can you help me please?
Thanks for your help

```
<?php


include '../include/classe_PDO.php';

$suivi = $_POST['suivi'];

// //ZIP PART
//Name zip folder with date
$dirzip = date('Ymd His')."_andromeda";

// Zip creation        
$nomzip = "C:/wamp64/www\Dylan/SAV/final/include/$dirzip.zip"; 
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip -> open($nomzip, ZipArchive::CREATE ) === TRUE)
{ 
    $dir = opendir($chemin); 
    while($fichier = readdir($dir)) 
    { 
        if(is_file($chemin.$fichier)) 
        { 
          $zip -> addFromString($file, $decoded);
        } 
    } 
    $zip ->close(); 
} 

//Zip download
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($nomzip).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nomzip));

flush();
readfile($nomzip);  
         

//DOWNLOAD PART
 try {
  // Connect to db
  $db = new db('mysql:dbname=jotform; host=localhost', 'root', '');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // Set SQL
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dhl` WHERE `submission_id` = :suivi";

  // Prepare query
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);

  // Execute query
  $query->execute(array(':suivi' => $suivi));

  foreach  ($query as $row) {
    
          $filedata = $row['label_envoi']; //get base64 data from query result
          $decoded = base64_decode($filedata); //decode base64 to binary

          $filedata2 = $row['label_retour']; //Second column
          $decoded2 = base64_decode($filedata2); 
          
          //set suitable HTTP response headers
          header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="label.pdf"');
          header('Expires: 0'); 
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate'); 
          header('Pragma: public'); 
          //output the binary file data in the body of the response
          echo $decoded;
          
  }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}        



?>
```

Comment: Instead of `addFile()`, use [`addFromString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php)

Comment: But how do I add my two files `$decode` and `$decode2` in my zip? I added the $chemin variable to test but my files are in my database

Comment: You would loop over the database and call `addFromString` on each row

Comment: So I have to put the creation of my zip in my foreach loop?

Comment: You would create the zip as above, and instead of using the `while` block to loop over a folder, you'd loop over the database rows

Comment: Like this `$zip -> addFromString($decoded.$file, $file);` ?

Comment: The code you've posted seems a bit confused. Is that your real code, or an amalagmation of an example and something you've written yourself? It makes no little sense overall that it's hard to tell.

Comment: P.S. `$zip -> addFromString($decoded.$file, $file);`...if `$decoded` contains the file data (as it does in your main code sample above), then you've put it into the wrong argument of the function and it's unclear why you've `$file` to it as well (which I guess contains the file name to use?). As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php, the first argument should be the file name, and the second should be the content. If my assumptions are correct then `$zip -> addFromString($file, $decoded);` would make more sense. You might need to check whether you need any of the flags

Comment: My first piece of code for creating the zip is a functional code that allows me to create a zip file and download it and the second allows me to download my PDF file from my database. Both work but I can't put them together hence my confusion... If I put in my current code the line you said a zip file is created but it remains empty. Maybe I'm not running it in the right order?

Comment: Maybe. Update the question with your attempt to merge the two pieces of code, including the usage of the addFromString function.

Comment: I just updated the description of the question and the title

Comment: That clarifies your request, but doesn't provide the code I asked for :-)

Comment: What does that mean? I changed added `$zip -> addFromString($file, $decoded);` in my code

Comment: yeah but it doesn't make any sense like that, because $decoded doesn't exist in that block of code. It would always be empty. You can't use that until you've also changed it to read from the database instead of the filesystem. that's why I asked you to show properly how you've attempted to merge these two pieces of code. Did you not do what Chris Haas indicated earlier, and replace the folder loop with the database loop?

Comment: I just modified my SQL query to avoid SQL injections, thanks. I see what you mean about the loop in the zip creation but I don't understand what exactly I have to add...

Comment: Another way to look at it is that you need to incorporate the bits for adding to the Zip file into your database loop code (rather than the other way round, if it's simpler to imagine). I've added a full code sample as an answer below, I think it should work although of course I have no real way to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your database rows and add each piece of decoded file data to the zip file. Then download the zip at the end.

For example:

```
include '../include/classe_PDO.php';

$suivi = $_POST['suivi'];

// //ZIP PART
//Name zip folder with date
$dirzip = date('Ymd His')."_andromeda";

// Zip creation        
$nomzip = "C:/wamp64/www/Dylan/SAV/final/include/$dirzip.zip"; 
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($nomzip, ZipArchive::CREATE ) === TRUE)
{
  try {
    //connect to DB
    $db = new db('mysql:dbname=jotform; host=localhost', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //prepare and execute query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dhl` WHERE `submission_id` = :suivi";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':suivi' => $suivi));

    foreach ($query as $row) {
      //decode base64 to binary
      $decoded = base64_decode($row['label_envoi']); 
      $decoded2 = base64_decode($row['label_retour']);
    
      //add to zip
      //N.B. if there could be more than one row returned by the database, you'll need to ensure the PDFs have unique names instead of these hard-coded ones
      $zip->addFromString("label1.pdf", $decoded);
      $zip->addFromString("label2.pdf", $decoded2);
    }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $zip ->close();

  //Zip download
  header('Content-Type: application/zip');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($nomzip).'"');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nomzip));

  flush();
  readfile($nomzip);
}
else
{
  echo "Error - Zip file could not be created";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanations. I have just tested the code, there are two things: the first one the zip file is created well on the server with the two files in it, but I have it on the server whereas I do not want it... The second is that the zip downloaded to the user remains empty while the correct one on the server

Comment: `I have it on the server whereas I do not want it`...you'll need to use a cron job to remove the generated zip files periodically. You can't create them on the fly as far as I know, at least not with the ZipArchive library anyway.

Comment: The zip being empty on download doesn't really make any sense though, if it's populated on the server then it should be populated on the client - it's exactly the same content which is served. You're not doing anything odd on the client-side like downloading the file via AJAX or anything, are you?

Comment: Okay I'll do that with a scheduled task for deletion. I agree with you it's weird, no my page is very basic, it's just an input where the user enters the tracking number and validates to retrieve the files in question

Comment: I tried it on another browser and it does the same thing. I do not understand knowing that the zip created on the server is good but the downloaded one is 0ko

Comment: It does sound bizarre. Have you checked the content-length header returned by the server? Or the raw response? The browser's Network tool (within the Developer Tools) can help you with that. Or you could test with a tool such as PostMan.

Comment: I added a picture of my console

Comment: Thanks. Which one of those is the download request? Have you looked inside it?

Comment: I have updated the pictures

Comment: Thanks, I can see the content-length is incorrectly 0 so we need to figure out why that is. Also, if you look inside the Response area for that request, is there any binary data visible, or is it empty?

Comment: No, when I go to the "Response" tab I get "Failed to load response data: no resouce with given identifier found"

Comment: Ok. Let's start with this: Just comment out the `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nomzip));` line entirely, and try again. it should not be essential anyway.

Comment: When I do this the downloaded zip file cannot open, it is 2k0 and the line in the console "content-lenght" disappears

Comment: `2k0` ...do you mean `2kb`? how big is the zip file on the server?

Comment: I had another idea, maybe we need to use `$zip-close();`. See updated code.

Comment: Yes!! That was it, I just saw that I had put it in my first code but not paid attention in yours. Thanks for your time we finally found the problem

Comment: No worries. I had also missed that from the original.